# Typo3 10 Cropping and resizing images in Typo3 Fluid doesn't work right

Tags: typo3, crop, fluid

I built a website in Typo3 10 for our customer.

In this website i use the FileReference cropping feature to get some images cropped in specific aspect ratios, like 1:1 or 2.35:1.
Over all it is working with following fluid-template

`<img src="{f:uri.image(image: '{page.wmNavImage}', width: 'c', height: 'c')}" alt="{page.title}" />`

When i use the big images and i would want to crop 1:1 with a maximum size of 256px it will either ignore the backend crop information, or have the images at full resolution, when i use the following template

`<img src="{f:uri.image(image: '{page.wmNavImage}', width: '256c', height: '256c')}" alt="{page.title}" />`

In this example it looks like it crops out a 256x256 part from my selected area from the backend

`<img src="{f:uri.image(image: '{page.wmNavImage}', width: 'c', height: 'c', maxWidth: '256', maxHeight: '256')}" alt="{page.title}" />`

with this i get the full image but resized to either 256 width or height, depends on what was the larger before

The image i really want is, my selection from backend in the selected ratio, but after cropping resized to said max width/height
Is there a way for the viewhelper to do this, or do i really have to resize the images before cropping?

Comment: I should add, that sometimes i use the same FileReference image as a Header-image in full screen 2.35:1 ratio and as a navigation image in 1:1 ratio

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have tested so many variants now, but never tested to leave the c away when adding a fixed width/height. So now it is following and finally works, like i always wanted it. When i only want to display the whole image as cropped in the backend, i needed the width: 'c' and height: 'c' unless it would only display the full image

`<img src="{f:uri.image(image: '{page.wmNavImage}', width: '256', height: '256')}" alt="{page.title}" />`

Comment: You might want to use `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` for better readability of the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip for anyone who experiences troubles with image cropping behaving strange:
Check if you need "c" suffix in fluid "width" and "height" properties for Image View Helper while "Image Manipulation" is enabled.

If any crop data is available for the image object, meaning the editor cropped the image in BE, then DO NOT USE "c" suffix in width or height values because it will collide and won't work as expected. Instead if you really need it then do some checks if image is cropped in back-end and according to that include or exclude "c" suffix from width or height properties.